# Printing directly to Ethernet printer using 'raster mode': need basic guidance

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa-touch, graphics, printing

I've stumbled across a problem *way* beyond my area of expertise, and I don't have a mentor to turn to for help with this.

I have a receipt printer I need to interface with through an iOS app. The printer is located on the same network as the device(s), so I can address it through supported "Line Mode commands"

What I'd like to do is keep the code I have already that works cross-platform – i.e. it's a UIView/NSView, and if you're not familiar with OS X/iOS, it's just a standard vanilla view that I can render into PDF/PNG formats. Thankfully, the printer has a "raster graphics" mode that seems to be what I need.

Unfortunately, be it the broken English of the command spec, or my complete lack of knowledge of anything beyond basic C, or my complete lack of knowledge regarding graphics, I have no idea how to even get started from the command specifications I have. I know the printer and my networking *works* because I can address it over the network and send it basic feed commands. But, I have no idea how to go from a PNG -> whatever the printer needs to make it's 'raster mode' work.

The specification is available at http://www.star-m.jp/eng/service/usermanual/linemode_cm_en.pdf , and the page you'd want to start reading it if you want to help is 3-68, and the specific commands I'm having trouble even getting started with are on 3-78/3-79.

I can give you nothing but a checkmark but I assure you, you'll have my undying gratitude if you can even provide me even a point in the right direction.

Comment: Please specify, do you also need help with converting the PNG to a printer raster format?  That is whole different topic in its own, color to black and white rasterisation, etc.

Comment: How do you connect to the printer? On a socket?

Comment: yep, socket. see my latest update below the other guys answer, I'm ridiculously close I think.

Comment: refulgentis, is that 320 per row hardcoded in your app, or do you mean the printer is hardcoded for 320? And the 1 byte per pixel, is that gray level?

Comment: Refulgentis, then you probably have to scale down to 256 pixels wide before printing.

Comment: +1 for: "I can give you nothing but a checkmark but I assure you, you'll have my undying gratitude if you can even provide me even a point in the right direction." :)

Comment: What is the exact model number of the printer?

Comment: It would be very interesting if someone could come in with a definitive answer. I am more and more intrigued, this should not be hard, and I am sure the final code will be pretty simple.

Comment: I know - it shouldn't be hard. If I had the printer I'm confident it'll be working in an hour or so.

Comment: Yes. @refulgentis, you could try to prototype this in a high level language of your choice on a PC or Mac, not related to an iPhone.

Comment: @refulgentis, see my last comment to @Richard Harrisons answer.

Comment: I think what I'd do next is to setup the CUPS driver and get that working, i.e. so you can print something to it from Mac/Linux. Then I'd capture the output from the CUPS driver and examine it with a hex editor to figure out where we're going wrong. I'm happy to help debug if you can setup the connection.

Comment: @refulgentis did you ever get this working?

Comment: ping                               pong. Did you get it to work?

Comment: Capturing the output of the CUPS driver is actually a very good idea. (@Richard Harrison.)

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a hunch this might be the same as the old Seiko printers, only yours is network enabled. If so, have a look at the [C code here](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/linux/system/printing/sii_printpbm-1.1.tar.gz). It tries to output to a serial port /dev/cua, where it thinks the printer is.

But if the commands are the same, the code should help you. It takes as input the [Portable Bitmap Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format), which is plain ASCII text.

But I don't know. [Microsoft indicates](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177512) Star Micronics works the same as Epson LQ, in which case there is [ample documentation](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/ESC/P).

Related links:

- [ESC/POS PDF Documentation](http://www.delfi.com/SupportDL/Epson/Manuals/TM-T88IV/Programming%20manual%20APG_1005_receipt.pdf), hundreds of pages
- [Command codes from the STAR website](http://www.starmicronics.com/support/download.aspx?type=5&tabText=StarESC/POS%C2%AE%20Mode%20Command%20Specifications&path=../support/Mannualfolder/escpos_cm_en.pdf&referrer=http://www.starmicronics.com/supports/supportmain.aspx&id=0)

---

Update! ;-) Try this, totally untested code:

```
/* Call with grayscale images of height 256, width 256. */

- (void) outputraster(char* pixels, int rows)
{
    const char initializeRaster[] =    "\x1B\x2A\x72\x52";
    const char enterRaster[] =         "\x1B\x2A\x72\x41";
    const char formFeed[] =            "\x1B\x0C\x00";
    const char clearRaster[] =         "\x1B\x2A\x72\x43";
    const char exitRaster[] =          "\x1B\x2A\x72\x42";

/* The FF means 255 lines: */
    char setRasterPageLength[]         "\x1B\x2A\x72\x50\xFF\x0";


/* The FF FF means 256 lines and 256 rows: */
    char sendRasterData[] =            "\x62\xFF\xFF";

    [self sendBytes:initializeRaster ofLength:sizeof(initializeRaster)];
    [self sendBytes:enterRaster ofLength:sizeof(enterRaster)];
    [self sendBytes:clearRaster ofLength:sizeof(clearRaster)];
    [self sendBytes:setRasterPageLength ofLength:sizeof(setRasterPageLength)];
    [self sendBytes:sendRasterData ofLength:sizeof(sendRasterData)];

    while (rows)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 255; x++)
        {
            [self sendBytes:pixels[x] ofLength:256];
        }

        rows --;
    }
}
```

**Update!**

---

I was looking at the docs at night, and stumbled upon how you can print out a prestored logo. Then I looked at how to define that logo, and that part of the documentation looked a [lot more thorough](http://vmlinux.org/jakov/star_logo_registering.pdf):
[image]
[image]
[image]

***Explanations of bitmap format [for a similar printer](https://web.archive.org/web/20061022233758/http://www.barcode-manufacturer.com/receipt_printer/printer_image_upload.html):***
[image]

Also, [look at pages 34 and on](http://www.star-m.jp/eng/service/usermanual/tsp552pm.pdf) for an explanation of the bitmap format of a Star printer.

Comment: hmm, it's very close, they definitely use the same basic ESCP based language, but ESCP/ESCP2 don't seem to have a 'raster mode' baked in, and another 45 min of searching based on that didn't turn up anything. have an upvote though! it's close.

Comment: @refulgentis, you could try run the codes anyway and see what happens. Sometimes hardware understands old commands even though it is not advertised in any manual. Yes, even if it works, it is considered bad to use undocumented features, but things like this seldom change anyway, so it might be OK.

Comment: aye, but the ESC/POS commands I found were based on sending ASCII strings and getting them printed. I need to be able to send arbitrary image data. That PHP class looks fascinating, will look through more.

Comment: Hm, it seems from the manual that you could update the font data of the "blank code page". This could be a way to write graphics. Update fonts to your graphic data. (I don't know if this is insane or not. This was how you programmed graphics on the Sinclair Spectrum.)

Comment: a little too insane for my blood. :P you might want to look at my last comment on the other question, since you've stuck with this and it's close.

Comment: Yes, I did. I will look at this more closely at home. I think it's pretty interesting. I have one of the old label writers at home somewhere. I will dig out and play with it.

Comment: hrmm...I don't think your sample code will work because the second and third bytes of sendRasterData[] should be the values that fit the equation (n1 + n2 * 256) = number of bytes being sent. Or is that wrong?

Comment: As I understand it, these are not proper equations. They just say that you must define an area to where on the paper you want to print. (n1, n2) Then d are the data rows, up to k rows, where k must a least one.

Comment: From reading the documents over and over, I'm pretty certain that  in raster mode the data is in X Y format rather than Y X, which is for line mode.

Comment: @Richard Harrison, either way, wouldn't that "just" result in the image printed flipped over?  Or totally garbled output?

Comment: @Amigable Clark Kant - for a square image it would be flipped, but otherwise it only the first column would be flipped, and the second column would start with the overspill or underspill from the first column etc.... that would probably look garbled...

Comment: @Richard Harrison, ah, yes of course - when you say it like that it seems so obvious. (Though it wasn't to me.) So in my (non-working, anyways) it would look "OK", only flipped. (Since I used a 256x256 image.)

Answer (score 12):

Having written a few printer drivers I can confirm that generally the documentation is confusing because of the way printers work. The document that you refer to doesn't actually seem to bad to me.

I think you're right to be printing in raster mode and that overall this is going to give the best results.

From the Star documentation I reckon you'll need to send :

```
1. \x1b*rR  Initialize raster mode
2. \x1b*rA  Enter raster mode
3. \x1b*rC  Clear raster data
4. \x1b*rml
4. b\x##\x##\xAA\xAA\xAA....<DATA>..........
5. \x1b\x0C\x00 Raster Form feed(??) - should spit out the data.
6. \x1b*rB  Clear raster data
```

*Obv*. in the above \x1b is the C encoding of ESC (i.e. character 27 0x1b).

From all of the documentation that I've been reading the following is how the images should be formatted in raster mode. When in line mode it is completely different as the vertical & horizontal are swapped. From [THERMAL PRINTER PROGRAMMER'S MANUAL (TSP552,TSP552II,TSP2000)](https://www.starmicronics.com/support/Mannualfolder/tsp552pm.pdf)

[image: Star Raster Data]

This equates to the following bytes stream.

[image: Star Raster bytes]

On the 4th command line it is effectively 'b' followed by two bytes definining the size. This size is computed as the number of pixels contained in the stream % 256 and / 256. So for 320x1 that'd 0x40,0x01

So, taking the above and plugging it into a simple test program you should test with this:

```
char rasterImage [] = {
0x1b, '*', 'r', 'R',       //  Initialize raster mode
0x1b, '*', 'r', 'A',       // Enter raster mode
0x1b, '*', 'r', 'C',       // Clear raster data
//          n1  n2 d1    d2..
0x1b, 'b', 0x2, 0, 0x00, 0x00, // data
0x1b, 'b', 0x2, 0, 0x1F, 0xF8,
0x1b, 'b', 0x2, 0, 0x3F, 0xFC,
0x1b, 'b', 0x2, 0, 0x77, 0xEE,
0x1b, 'b', 0x2, 0, 0xF8, 0x1F,
0x1b, 'b', 0x2, 0, 0xF8, 0x1F,
0x1b, 'b', 0x2, 0, 0xF8, 0x1F,
0x1b, 'b', 0x2, 0, 0x0F, 0xF0,
0x1b, 'b', 0x2, 0, 0x1F, 0xF8,
0x1b, 'b', 0x2, 0, 0x1F, 0xF8,
0x1b, 'b', 0x2, 0, 0x3E, 0x7C,
0x1b, 'b', 0x2, 0, 0x38, 0x1C,
0x1b, 'b', 0x2, 0, 0x79, 0x9E,
0x1b, 'b', 0x2, 0, 0x73, 0xCE,
0x1b, 'b', 0x2, 0, 0x73, 0xCE,
0x1b, 'b', 0x2, 0, 0xF9, 0x9F,
0x1b, 'b', 0x2, 0, 0xF8, 0x1F,
0x1b, 'b', 0x2, 0, 0xFE, 0x7F,
0x1b, 'b', 0x2, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF,
0x1b, 'b', 0x2, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF,
0x1b, 'b', 0x2, 0, 0x00, 0x00,
0x1b, 'b', 0x2, 0, 0x00, 0x00,
0x1b, 'b', 0x2, 0, 0x00, 0x00,
0x1b, 'b', 0x2, 0, 0x00, 0x00};

[self.currentDataBeingSent appendBytes:rasterImage length:sizeof(rasterImage)];
```

Simply squirt that out to the printer and you should get a picture as above. This is where you can easily tweak and play about with the exact commands to get something that's working. Often this is the only way I've ever managed to figure out what should be done.

### rev.3

Ref. comments.

If you have a byte per pixel then you will need to merge these into a series of bits; the following should do the job based on your pastebin code. I've also changed the `char*` to be unsigned as it is signed can cause problems when bit manipulating.

```
NSUInteger bitmapBytePerRow = width/8;
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = 3 + bitmapBytePerRow;

[self.currentDataBeingSent = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:bytesPerRow * height];
[self.currentDataBeingSent appendBytes:initializeRaster length:sizeof(initializeRaster)];
[self.currentDataBeingSent appendBytes:enterRaster length:sizeof(enterRaster)];

NSUInteger byteOffset = 0;
for (NSUInteger y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    unsigned char *rasterCommandForRow = (unsigned char *)calloc(bytesPerRow, sizeof(char));
    unsigned char *current_raster = rasterCommandForRow; 
    *current_raster++ = '\x6B';     
    *current_raster++ = (width*height) % 256;
    *current_raster++ = (width*height) / 256;
    
    unsigned char mask = '\x80' ;
    unsigned char out = 0 ;
    for (NSUInteger x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        if (*(data + (byteOffset * sizeof(char))))
            out |= mask ;
        byteOffset++;
        mask >>= 1 ;
        if( 0 == mask )
        {
            mask = '\x80' ;
            *current_raster++ = out ;
            if( out )
        lastDot = nextOut ;
            out = 0 ;
        }
        
    }
    
    // handle partially finished byte .
    if( ( '\x80' != mask ) && ( 0 != out ) )
        *current_raster++ = out ;

    [self.currentDataBeingSent appendBytes:rasterCommandForRow length:bytesPerRow];
}
```

### rev.3a

Looking at the [Mac CUPS support](http://www.star-m.jp/cgi/s_print_download_e.cgi?file=starcupsdrv-3.1.1_mac_20100423.zip) from Star it's got the source code for the driver which contains a lot of clues about how this should be done. Sometimes code is so much easier to read than documentation.

`starcupsdrv-3.1.1_mac_20100423.zip\starcupsdrv-3.1.1_mac\SourceCode\`

contains `starcupsdrv-src-3.1.1.tar.gz\` sub folder `starcupsdrv\src\`

View rastertostar.c, the important bit is the calculation of the n1 / n2 values. These aren't at all X & Y but based on the pixel count, lastBlackPixel is the count of pixels from the source.

```
putchar('b');
putchar((char) ((lastBlackPixel > 0)?(lastBlackPixel % 256):1));
putchar((char) (lastBlackPixel / 256));
```

I've modified the code above to include the fixes, hopefully that'll be closer. If not post a scan of what comes out of the printer, it will be useful to diagnose what's happening.

For reference The code between 580:650 from [jsStarUSB.cpp](http://boundarydevices.com/git?p=bdScript.git;a=blob;f=jsStarUSB.cpp) seems to me to be along the lines of what you need to produce a buffer (stored in `nextOut`) that contains the raster data in the format to be sent directly to the printer.

### rev. 4 (2023)

Joshua May advises in the comments that rasterImage doesn't need the ESC (0x1b) on each row - only the 'b' and that by just removing the 0x1b "worked for me".

Comment: very, very, close...I was able to implement your test and I also took a stab at what I need. here's the (very naive) code I have so far: http://pastebin.com/8g8CGFBp . Assume that data is an argument that contains bitmap data with 1 byte per pixel. It gets something to the printer, but the printer just prints out garbage over what looks like 4-6 lines. (I should note the pixels per row is hardcoded at 320 because that's a given too) Any ideas?

Comment: refulgentis, is that 320 per row hardcoded in your app, or do you mean the printer is hardcoded for 320? And the 1 byte per pixel, is that gray level?

Comment: same issue with the new code :/ and now my data grows to exactly 2 times the length it should. I'm sorry I suck at C and can't debug this myself. current code: http://pastebin.com/sxeBbVzs

Comment: Hm,oh, the part about the bits is important. :-/

Comment: There are a couple of bugs in http://pastebin.com/sxeBbVzs, firstly bytesPerRow should be `bitmapBytePerRow = width/8`, secondly you're allocating rasterCommandForRow and then using it as a pointer thus losing the original address. Revision posted.

Comment: Still doesn't work at all. :/ I know this is beyond the scope of anything possible at this point, so thanks for your help. I'll just switch to line mode. :/

Comment: Don't give up.. I've found some more code and will post a revision. Need to know model number.

Comment: Very, very interesting. I upvoted early on. I also thought about checking out the CUPS driver if there was anything there, but couldn't muster the willpower and time right now. But suggesting him to post a scan of the print-out - EPIC! ++ for thinking about it and also be bothered to suggest it. Nice touch!

Comment: @Richard Harrison, @refulgentis:  couldn't you (refulgentis) put your printer on the Internet and give Richard H. the IP address to it? A bit unorthodox, but you could have a little debug session with each other. @refulgentis, if you could rig a webcam via Skype, MSN or something, pointing at the printer, So Richard H. could see what he prints, would be awesome.

Comment: @Richard Harrison: TPS650 @Clark Kant: not the worst idea I've ever heard! Let me know if you're interested Richard.

Comment: I'd be happy to try to help debug this directly.

Comment: good lord, still doesn't work, even with just the simple test command being sent. It wasn't printing anything, so I threw a form feed in after but that didn't help, except now it spits a 3-4 cm piece out. I'll have to think of a way to get this on the internet with a webcam watching so you can see.

Comment: FWIW, the current code: http://pastebin.com/yCVfVZ1i . Duplicates order of commands and everything sent as from the CUPS driver. Only difference at this point should be the actual raster data.

Comment: The code looks OK to me; very strange. I think what I'd do next is to setup the CUPS driver and get that working, i.e. so you can print something to it from Mac/Linux. Then I'd capture the output from the CUPS driver and examine it with a hex editor to figure out where we're going wrong..

Comment: This is a pretty old post at this point, but nearly a decade later I figured I'd chime in with what helped me :)

`rasterImage` doesn't need the `ESC` (`0x1b`) on each row - only the `'b'`. Literally just remove the `0x1b`s and you should see some output. At least, that worked for me! :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps someone, but I was trying to use the code from Richard Harrison above to print the phone raster in Python...

I on my system I can run `python3 raster.py > /dev/usb/lp0` and I get the expected output!! Hopefully it shows what you need. I cross refrenced the bytes of a file that would print, and also the graphical mode manual.

```
import sys

buf = [
  0x1b, ord('*'), ord('r'), ord('A'),                  # enter raster mode
  0x1b, ord('*'), ord('r'), ord('P'), ord('0'), 0x00,  # continuous mode
  ord('b'), 0x2, 0, 0x00, 0x00,
  ord('b'), 0x2, 0, 0x1F, 0xF8,
  ord('b'), 0x2, 0, 0x3F, 0xFC,
  ord('b'), 0x2, 0, 0x77, 0xEE,
  ord('b'), 0x2, 0, 0xF8, 0x1F,
  ord('b'), 0x2, 0, 0xF8, 0x1F,
  ord('b'), 0x2, 0, 0xF8, 0x1F,
  ord('b'), 0x2, 0, 0x0F, 0xF0,
  ord('b'), 0x2, 0, 0x1F, 0xF8,
  ord('b'), 0x2, 0, 0x1F, 0xF8,
  ord('b'), 0x2, 0, 0x3E, 0x7C,
  ord('b'), 0x2, 0, 0x38, 0x1C,
  ord('b'), 0x2, 0, 0x79, 0x9E,
  ord('b'), 0x2, 0, 0x73, 0xCE,
  ord('b'), 0x2, 0, 0x73, 0xCE,
  ord('b'), 0x2, 0, 0xF9, 0x9F,
  ord('b'), 0x2, 0, 0xF8, 0x1F,
  ord('b'), 0x2, 0, 0xFE, 0x7F,
  ord('b'), 0x2, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF,
  ord('b'), 0x2, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF,
  ord('b'), 0x2, 0, 0x00, 0x00,
  ord('b'), 0x2, 0, 0x00, 0x00,
  ord('b'), 0x2, 0, 0x00, 0x00,
  ord('b'), 0x2, 0, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x1b, ord('*'), ord('r'), ord('b') # end raster mode
]

blob = bytearray(buf)
sys.stdout.buffer.write(blob)
```

EDIT: Off the back of this, I created a Python library that will take an image and convert it into the required raster commands... https://pypi.org/project/StarTSPImage/