# How to Program in C for Hengstler C51 Thermal receipt Printer

Tags: c, printing

I am working on project where I need to print a receipt through a Hengstler C51 Thermal Printer. The device is working fine and it's printing images too.

I need to write a C program which can open my printer and print my preformatted receipt which is going to contain a simple logo.

I can not figure out how to proceed.

The API Documentations given by Hengstler really stinks. I installed all their drivers and API libs though. I am using Ubuntu 11.04.

I am looking for some sample or demo programs to start from.

Comment: might just be easier to make program that creates your image file instead of programming the printer. I can't find anything on this thing. Your best bet is to trial and error on that API and Docs they provide, if you don't like my idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995703/printing-directly-to-ethernet-printer-using-raster-mode-need-basic-guidance  <-- check this. Many, many thermal printers use the same or similar Star derived command set. But Johns advice above is good.

Comment: Also, what kind of images and how do you print those?  Through the Ubuntu CUPS system?  You can also just create a Postscript file then with the receipt.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato, suggest that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

might just be easier to make program that creates your image file instead of programming the printer. I can't find anything on this thing. Your best bet is to trial and error on that API and Docs they provide, if you don't like my idea.